# How to avoid query taking long time when adding new node to cluster

Tags: cassandra

I found query (just a simple select query) takes long time when adding a new node to cluster.

My execution time log :

```
17:49:40.008 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-14] INFO  task.DiskCounting - void task.DiskCounting.runJob()  executed in 8 ms
17:50:00.010 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-3] INFO  task.DiskCounting - void task.DiskCounting.runJob()  executed in 15010 ms
17:50:15.008 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-4] INFO  task.DiskCounting - void task.DiskCounting.runJob()  executed in 10008 ms
17:50:20.008 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-16] INFO  task.DiskCounting - void task.DiskCounting.runJob()  executed in 7 ms
```

Normally it takes about 10ms, and suddently takes 15000ms when adding node.

And I found it stuck because waiting for new node init data

Cassandra log (the new node):

```
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/194.187.1.52] 2019-05-31 17:49:36,056 OutboundTcpConnection.java:560 - Handshaking version with /194.187.1.52
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2019-05-31 17:49:36,059 Gossiper.java:1055 - Node /194.187.1.52 is now part of the cluster
INFO  [RequestResponseStage-1] 2019-05-31 17:49:36,069 Gossiper.java:1019 - InetAddress /194.187.1.52 is now UP
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2019-05-31 17:49:36,109 TokenMetadata.java:479 - Updating topology for /194.187.1.52
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2019-05-31 17:49:36,109 TokenMetadata.java:479 - Updating topology for /194.187.1.52
INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-05-31 17:49:39,347 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_traces as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-05-31 17:49:39,352 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system_traces.events
INFO  [MigrationStage:1] 2019-05-31 17:49:39,382 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system_traces.sessions
```

Stuck when : Node /194.187.1.52 is now part of the cluster

And client will wait for new node init all data

What I have tried:

```
1. I try use consistency with ONE or QUORUM, and is no difference

2. I try turn replication factor to 1, 2 or 3, and still no difference
```

Why new node become part of cluster when that node not init data completely.

Is there a way to solve this.

I expect when I query to old node, the performance is not influenced by just waiting for new node to init data.

---

.
.
.

I resolved this problem.

I write wrong config, I let all node become seeds even before they joining cluster, this cause read timed-out during adding new node to cluster.

After fix this. all read is normal, but somehow I found insert query timed-out during adding node.

Finally I tune this to avoid insert timed-out:

```
/sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5
```

and also change conf to limit throughput

```
stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec : 100
```

Really thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a theory, but one possible cause of this is that the new node is being chosen as a coordinator by your driver client, in this case, consistency level and replication aren't the main contributing factor to the delay in servicing your query.

If the new node is slowly performing initially for whatever reason and the driver is sending requests to it, the behavior of the coordinator can impact the servicing of your request.

What exactly is `runJob` doing?  You suggested it is making a single query, but is it possible that it's a range query?

If it's a single query and it's taking as long as 10 seconds, that seems odd as the default `read_request_timeout` is 5 seconds.  If it's a range query (a read involving multiple partitions), the default is 10 seconds.  Are you adjusting those timeouts?

When you see responses that long for a single query that could mean the coordinator is what is impeding responsiveness as otherwise if the coordinator was responsive and the replicas were slow, you'd see `ReadTimeoutException` message serviced to the client.

To better react to these cases, a number of client drivers implement a strategy called 'speculative execution'.  As described in the [documentation for the DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/speculative_execution/):

> Sometimes a Cassandra node might be experiencing difficulties (ex: long GC pause) and take longer than usual to reply. Queries sent to that node will experience bad latency.
>
> One thing we can do to improve that is pre-emptively start a second execution of the query against another node, before the first node has replied or errored out. If that second node replies faster, we can send the response back to the client (we also cancel the first execution – note that “cancelling” in this context simply means discarding the response when it arrives later, Cassandra does not support cancellation of in flight requests at this stage)

You could configure your driver to speculatively execute with a constant threshold for idempotent requests (such as reads are).  In the 3.x java driver, its done this way:

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
  .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
  .withSpeculativeExecutionPolicy(
    new ConstantSpeculativeExecutionPolicy(
      500, // delay before a new execution is launched
      2    // maximum number of executions
  ))
  .build();
```

In this case, if the coordinator was slow to respond, after 500ms the driver chooses another coordinator and submits a second quest, and the first coordinator to respond wins.

Note that this might cause an amplification of requests sent to your cluster overall, so you want to tune that delay in such a way that it only kicks in when response time is highly anomalous.  In your case, if requests normally take less than 10ms, 500ms is probably a reasonable number depending on what your higher percentile latencies look like.

All that being said, if you are able to identify that the problem is the new node behaving poorly as a coordinator.  It's worth understanding why.  Adding speculative execution could be a nice way of possibly working around the problem, but it's probably better to try to understand why the new node is so slowly performing.  Having monitoring in place to observe Cassandra's metrics would likely give great visibility into the problem.

Comment: Really thanks for your help, finally I solved problem, and I update to the post.

Answer (score 2):

That is a behaviour that you can find with too high consistency, or not having enough copies of data (replication factor). When a new node is added to the cluster, a rearrangement of the ownership of tokens occur, once that it is determined what data will the new node be the owner, it will start streaming that data, which may saturate the network.

In your question you don't mention the network setting or if you are using cloud instances, which have a direct impact for these constraints, for example, an AWS m3.large instance will be more restricted in network capabilities than an i3.4xlarge.

Other variable to consider is disk configuration, if you are using your own hardware look for the cap in IO of your drives settings; if you are on the cloud, using the instance storage, when available, will have a better performance than external volumes ( as AWS EBS; if this is the case, ensure that you are enabling the " EBS optimized" option if your instance allows it)

Usually a RF of 3 with consistency level of Quorum should also help you to prevent the issue.

Comment: Really thanks for your help, finally I solved problem, and I update to the post.